# If $B$ is the Borel sigma algebra on a metric space $X$ and $\{F_a\}$ is a family of closed subsets of $X$, then $\bigcap_a F_a \in B$.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

I conjectured the following statement and attempted a proof. Can you please verify whether my proof is correct?

If $B$ is the Borel sigma algebra on a metric space $X$ and $\{F_a\}$ is a family of closed subsets of $X$, then $\bigcap_a F_a \in B$.

**Proof.** Let $\mathcal{T}$ denote the collection of open subsets of $X$, i.e., the topology on $X$. Let $\{F_a : a \in A\}$ be a collection of closed subsets of $X$. Then $F_a^c \in \mathcal{T}$ for all $a \in A$. But $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology, so $\bigcup_{a\in A}F_a^c \in \mathcal{T}$. The Borel sigma algebra is the sigma algebra generated by the open sets in $\mathcal{T}$, so $\bigcup_{a\in A}F_a^c \in B$ and therefore $\bigcap_{a\in A} F_a = \left(\bigcup_{a\in A}F_a^c\right)^c  \in \mathcal{T}$.

**Related question**

Does the statement hold if we replace $\bigcap_{a\in A} F_a$ by $\bigcup_{a\in A} F_a$?

Comment: The proof looks good - you're basically saying that the intersection of closed sets is closed, and every closed set belongs to $B$. For the related question, note that single points are closed in a metric space, and _every_ subset of $X$ is the union of single points!

Comment: Thanks. So, for the related question: it must be false. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric. Choose a set $V$ that is not Lebesgue measurable, such as the Vitali set. Then $F = \{\{v\} : v \in V\}$ is a collection of closed subsets of $X$. Yet, $\cup F = \cup_{v \in V}\{v\} = V$ is not Lebesgue measurable, and therefore not Borel measurable.